# Compiling Swift Resource is Stuck in Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7

I have a very small App ,2 Swift Files , no images 
Parse and Bolts pods + Flurry.h framework
when trying to Archive , the system is Stuck at "Compiling Swift Resources"

I have Cleaned the project 
I have Closed and Opened Xcode,my Mac 
I have Changed the Optimisation Level to " Fast " in build Settings

Nothing works !!

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Is this during archiving ?

Comment: Yes also during analyzing

Answer (score 0):

This might be an Xcode 7.0.1 bug related to LLVM. See [this report](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/53383) on Apple Dev forum

Comment: So solution to do it in objective c or what exactly do you recommend?

Comment: Xcode 7.1 is out today. Update and see if you face the issue or not

Answer (score 0):

I have Removed Flurry , & the Issue is solved !